# Computation of scalar curvature from a Riemannian metric

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

I want to compute the scalar curvature for points on an empirical manifold (sampled data).

I have already an algorithm that learns the Riemannian metric and computes geodesics, so from the metric I can compute the Christoffel symbols.
However the scalar curvature is defined in terms of Christoffel symbols and their derivatives, and I do not know how to compute the derivatives given the metric.

In particular the scalar curvature is defined as
$$ S = g^{\mu \nu} \left[  \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu \nu, \lambda} -  \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu \lambda, \nu} +  \Gamma^{\sigma}_{\mu \nu}  \Gamma^{\lambda}_{ \lambda \sigma} -  \Gamma^{\sigma}_{\mu \lambda}  \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\nu \sigma}\right] $$

where $ \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu \nu, \lambda}$ is the derivative wrt to the coordinate $x^{\lambda}$  of the Christoffel symbol $ \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu \nu}$. With $g^{\mu \nu}$ I indicate the inverse metric, i.e. $g^{\mu \nu} = (g^{-1})_{\mu \nu}$.  ( Here I use Einstein notation so repeated symbols on upper and lower script indicate summation over that index).

Is there some some of relationship that I ignore for obtaining the derivatives of the Christoffel symbols based only on the metric in a similar vein as one computed the symbols themselves from the metric?

Comment: Take the formula for the Christoffel symbols given in terms of the metric and differentiate it.... This is an ugly computation, and it will likely help a good deal to work in exponential coordinates if that is feasible. Worth mentioning that any formula for the scalar curvature will need two derivatives of the metric to be present.

Comment: @AlexNolte I know that it ends up being particularly ugly. That's why I asked here if there is some trick that I am not aware of.

Comment: Symmetries of the curvature tensor can simplify the computation considerably in low-dimensional cases, e.g. in isothermal coordinates in dimension 2. In exponential coordinates in general, at the center point $g_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$ and $\Gamma_{ij}^k = 0$, which eliminates many terms. One shouldn't expect a non-ugly formula in general. Perhaps worth mentioning that there's a characterization of scalar curvature involving no Christoffel symbols in terms of local volume growth comparison to Euclidean space, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_curvature#Direct_geometric_interpretation.

Comment: @AlexNolte Yes, I have been thinking about comparing the volume of unit balls to have a fast coarse estimate for the curvature.  Let's see if I find the analytic calculation too cumbersome or too slow I might as well resort to some sort of approximation through unit ball volume comparison. Thank you very much for your help!